# Implement a predicate subtraction

Tags: prolog

So far, my program can add two numbers together.

`s(0)` represents `1`, `s(s(0))` represents `2` and so on

`p(0)` represents `-1`, `p(p(0))` is `-2` etc.

I want to be able to call a program such that

```
add2(s(s(0)), p(0), Z).
```

returns

```
Z = s(0).
```

My code is as follows:

```
numeral(0).
numeral(s(X)) :- numeral(X).

add(0,X,X).
add(s(X),Y,s(Z)) :- add(X,Y,Z).

numeral(X+Y) :- numeral(X), numeral(Y).

add2(X,Y,Z):-add(X,Y,Z).
add2(X+Y, Z,A) :-add(X,Y,R),add2(R,Z,A).
add2(Z,X+Y,A) :-add(X,Y,R),add2(Z,R,A).

numeral(p(X)) :- numeral(X).

add2(p(X),Y,p(Z)) :- add2(X,Y,Z).
p(s(X)) =:= 0.
s(p(X)) =:= 0.
```

My logic was that if `p(s(0))` was in the list, it would just equate it to `0`.. I was wrong, however. Does anybody know where to go with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each numeral could be represented only in one of these 3 ways:

- `0` - null;
- `s(X)` - next, where `X` is numeral;
- `p(X)` - previous, where `X` is numeral;

`add2/3` should take 2 numerals and return sum of them. It could be defined manually for each possible arguments:

```
add2(0, 0, 0).
add2(0, s(X), Y) :- Y = s(X).
add2(0, p(X), Y) :- Y = p(X).

add2(s(X), 0, Y) :- Y = s(X).
add2(s(X), s(Y), Z) :- add2(X, Y, s(s(Z))).
add2(s(X), p(Y), Z) :- add2(X, Y, Z).

add2(p(X), 0, Y) :- Y = p(X).
add2(p(X), s(Y), Z) :- add2(X, Y, Z).
add2(p(X), p(Y), Z) :- add2(X, Y, p(p(Z))).
```

Works well:

```
?- add2(s(s(0)), p(0), Z).
Z = s(0) .
```

It is notable that many cases of `add2/3` rule is actually overlapped and could be eliminated:

```
add2(0, X, X).
add2(X, 0, X).

add2(s(X), s(Y), Z) :- add2(X, Y, s(s(Z))).
add2(s(X), p(Y), Z) :- add2(X, Y, Z).

add2(p(X), s(Y), Z) :- add2(X, Y, Z).
add2(p(X), p(Y), Z) :- add2(X, Y, p(p(Z))).
```